# Scroll view inside bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a scroll view inside bootstrap panel. The problem is that my scroll view is absolute and it start at the top of my panel. So it hide a part of the panel title.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}


#right {
  height:100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
      <p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p>
  </div>   

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
      <p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

How can I do to make it start under the panel title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the #right top: 42px (shown below) if you don't want to do .panel-body position:relative.

Hope this helps

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}


#right {
  height:100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
      <p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p>
  </div>   

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
      <p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to give a `top` value for your right div:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}

#right {
  height:100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
      <p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p>
  </div>   

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
      <p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your yellow panel is appearing over the panel title is because the `.panel-body` div (which is the parent div to the #right div) does not have `position: relative` styles added to it.

I have copied your code snippet and added the little bit of code you were missing.

EDIT:

As my suggestion above caused the scrolling to stop working, I have removed the `position: relative` from your panel-body div and added `42px` to the top value for your absolutely positioned div. Now the scrolling will work.

However as you are using bootstrap I don't understant why you don't just use that to put 2 divs next to each other. Take a look at this fiddle that leverages the use of Bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/sdkow4v2/

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
}


#right {
  height:100%;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="left">
      <p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p><p>Left content</p>
  </div>   

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="right">
      <p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p><p>Right content</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ehhh it doesn't scroll anymore

Answer (score 0):

If the absolute div going out of your panel-body, Then you missed one thing:

You have to wrap the parent div with position relative

i.e.

```
.panel-body{
position:relative;
}
```

What the absolute div will do is it will take top and left coordinates relatively to the panel-body. if you are not using position:relative to the parent div(panel-body) then right panel div will take top and left coordinates value relatively to the body tag.